# Regex to find anchor tag consist of new line in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to find the href from an achore tag. So I have used regex as

```
 <a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*\=\s*([^(\s*|\>)]*)\s*[^>]*>\s*Text\s*<\/a>
 Options = Ignorecase + singleline
```

Example

```
    <a href="/abc/xzy/pqr.com" class="m">Text</a>
So Group[1]="/abc/xzy/pqr.com"
```

But If the content is like

```
     <a href="/abc/xzy/                     //Contains new line
    pqr.com" class="m">Text</a>  


so Group[1]="/abc/xzy/
```

So I want to know how to get "/abc/xzy/pqr.com" if the content contains new line(\r\n)

Comment: don't use regex to parse html, htmlagilitypack.

Comment: `htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your capture group is a bit weird: `[^(\s*|\>)]*` is a character class and it will match any character not `(`, ror a character class `\s`, nor an asterisk `*`, etc.

What you can do however is to put quotes before and after the capture group:

```
<a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*\=\s*"([^(\s*|\>)]*)"\s*[^>]*>\s*Text\s*<\/a>
                         ^              ^
```

And then change the character class to `[^"]` (not quotes):

```
<a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*\=\s*"([^"]*)"\s*[^>]*>\s*Text\s*<\/a>
                           ^^^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/zF0mT8).

This said, it would be better to use a proper html parser instead of regex. It's just that it's more tedious to make a suitable regex because you can forget about a lot of different scenarios, but if you're certain of how your data comes through, regex might be a quick way to get what you need.

If you want to consider single quotes and no quotes at all in some cases, you might try this instead:

```
<a\s*[^>]*\s*href\s*=\s*((?:[^ ]|[\n\r])+)\s*[^>]*>\s*Text\s*<\/a>
```

[Updated regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/fU3pI8).

This regex has this part instead `(?:[^ ]|[\n\r])+` which accepts non-spaces and newlines (and carriage returns just in case). Note that `\s` contains white spaces, tabs, newlines and form-feed.

Comment: As I have to consider '," or without any quotes eg "/abc/xzy/pqr.com",'/abc/xzy/pqr.com',/abc/xzy/pqr.com, /abc/xz'y/pqr.com