# Regex to find the href from anchore tag for specific cases in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some specific cases for which regex does not fit.

Examples

```
  1.  <a href="abnvb/m'hhjhh/js   jmm" hbbnb="bbn">bhjbhj</a>-----containing quote(') in between " " and having space in between
  2.  <a href="vvvbg" jhhbhh="tyrty">gffgd</a>
  3.  <a href=**abyuyyuub/m'hhjhh/js jmm**    hbbnb="bbn">bhjbhj</a>----without quotes having space
```

I have used the regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503631/regex-to-find-anchor-tag-consist-of-new-line-in-c-sharp-net)

My regex is as below

```
<a\s+[^>]*\s*href\s*=('|"|)\s*((?:[^\1|>]|[\n\r])+)(\1)[ |>][^>]*?>(.*?)</a>
```

So 1 and 2 works fine but for 3 it gives

```
abyuyyuub/m'hhjhh/js jmm but it should be
abyuyyuub/m'hhjhh/js
```

Also I want to know how to match the first occurrence i.e. how to match the first double quote("),single quote(') or space

Comment: [It is a bad idea to use regex for HTML parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Instead of trying to parse  the entire tag with Regex, just extract the href and parse it using Uri.TryParse

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on having that particular regex satisfying all three examples - you should add an `\s` to the exclusion in the non-capture group inside the second capture group: `[^\1|>]` to `[^\1\s|>]`, resulting in:

```
<a\s+[^>]*\s*href\s*=('|"|)\s*((?:[^\1\s|>]|[\n\r])+)(\1)[ |>][^>]*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Overall it is of course a "bad idea" (tm) to parse urls in this way, as previously mentioned in the comments.